# Separate transaction on Java spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I'm not quite sure on how to do this. But I'm finding a way to separate the transactions of the functions.

I have a listener that processes the results of each messages (`messageListener`). And before sending it to the next step (`sendToNextProcess`), I'd like to make sure that the first transaction(`updateMessagesResults`) was successful. (Create a separate transaction perhaps?)

How do I do this on Java Spring? Thank you

```
public void messageListener(List<Message> messages) {
    resultUpdater.updateMessagesResults(messages);
    sendToNextProcess(messages);
}
```

Note: Both the listener and the resultUpdater have the `@Transactional` annotations.

Thank you!

Comment: Mark the `updateMessagesResult` as `REQUIRES_NEW` as the propagation level. That will start a new transaction for the `updateMessageResults`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `REQUIRES_NEW` on both `sendToNextProcess` and `updateMessagesResults`

and don't call `sendToNextProcess` directly because it will not work you should inject the current service and call it from like this

```
@Service
public CurrentService {
    @Autowire
    CurrentService CurrentService;  

    @Transactional
    public void messageListener(List<Message> messages) {
        resultUpdater.updateMessagesResults(messages);
        currentService.sendToNextProcess(messages);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void sendToNextProcess(List<Message> messages) {

    }
}
```

why you should call it from injected service because the `@transactional` 
tries to wrap it from outside the class scope and then it tries to call it with `this` and it will not work as  you expect